# Change password on user request PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, prepared-statement

I am trying to make a php script which checks if the email is in db, then randomly generates password, changes it in database and sends email informing the user. The code correctly checks if the entered email is valid, but it does not change the password. Pasting the code and thank you in advance. I am a beginner so please try avoid criticizing about having bad code, I am here to learn.

```
require_once("database/DatabaseConnection.php");

unset($_SESSION['success_message']);
unset($_SESSION['error_message']);


function died($error)
{
    // your error code can go here
    echo "We are very sorry, but you have to input correct email. ";
    echo "If there was anything else you will see errors below.<br /><br />";
    echo $error . "<br /><br />";
    echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
    die();
}

// validation expected data exists
if (!isset($_POST['logMail'])) {
    died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');
}


$email = $_POST['logMail']; // required

$error_message = "";
$email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';

if (!preg_match($email_exp, $email)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
}

function randomPassword()
{
    $alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890';
    $pass = array(); //remember to declare $pass as an array
    $alphaLength = strlen($alphabet) - 1; //put the length -1 in cache
    for ($i = 0; $i < 8; $i++) {
        $n = rand(0, $alphaLength);
        $pass[] = $alphabet[$n];
    }
    return implode($pass); //turn the array into a string
}


function sendPSW()
{
    $pass = randomPassword();
    $email = $_POST['logMail'];
    $newpsw = password_hash($pass, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

    // create PDO connection object
    $dbConn = new DatabaseConnection();
    $pdo = $dbConn->getConnection();

    try {
        $statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE email = :email LIMIT 1");
        $statement->bindParam(':email', $email);
        $statement->execute();

        $result = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        // no user matching the email
        if (empty($result)) {
            $_SESSION['error_message'] = 'Invalid email!';
            echo "WRONG EMAIL";
            return;
        }
            $sql = "UPDATE users SET password=:$newpsw WHERE email = :email";

            // Prepare statement
            $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);

            // execute the query
            $stmt->execute();


            if ($stmt->query($sql) === TRUE) {
                echo "Record updated successfully";
                $subject = "Password Update Request";
                $mailContent = 'Dear Customer, 
            <br/>Sending your randomly generated password, make sure you change it once logged in.
            <br/>Here is your temporary password: ' . $pass . '
            <br/><br/>Regards,
            <br/>eSHOP';
                //set content-type header for sending HTML email
                $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
                $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
                //additional headers
                $headers .= 'From: eSHOP' . "\r\n";
                //send email
                mail($email, $subject, $mailContent, $headers);
                return true;
            } else {
                echo "Error updating record";
                die();

            }

    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        // usually this error is logged in application log and we should return an error message that's meaninful to user
        return $e->getMessage();
    }
}
       }
       sendPSW();
```

Comment: @chris85 can you tell me how to bind and make a static binding, I got confused

Comment: *"I am a beginner"* ... `$newpsw = password_hash($pass, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);` <- this makes me happy :) Looks like you're heading in the right direction.

Comment: Don't use a regex for validating email.. PHP has a FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL option to be used with function filter_var...

Comment: Sending passwords in plain text is never a good idea. Get them to change it directly on your site and send them a confirmation token, and only change it in your db once you receive the confirmation token back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This statement is building a parameterized query, as you have elsewhere; but it should have a static value for the password's placeholder. So

```
$sql = "UPDATE users SET password=:$newpsw WHERE email = :email";
```

Should be:

```
$sql = "UPDATE users SET password=:newpsw WHERE email = :email";
```

and then the `execute` needs to have the bindings defined:

```
// Prepare statement
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
// execute the query
$update_status = $stmt->execute(array(':newpsw' => $newpsw, ':email' => $email));
```

Then remove the `query()` call from `$stmt->query($sql)` because that will re-execute the query and `query()` won't work with parameterized queries ( and should never be used with user provided data anyway. It is best to always use `prepare` and `execute`). Check that `$update_status` is TRUE and your query should have worked.

Comment: This is good but I would not call this static binding; that means something else in PHP. Just plain binding or variable binding is better.

Comment: Yes, that’s right - it’s just the use of `static` that’s possibly confusing in that context.

Comment: @Synchro Okay, I've removed that and reworded it to avoid confusion.